# Open XSL file in Browser and show as Code - How?

Tags: html, xslt

```
<a href="s.xsl"> XSL </a>
```

If I click on it, it shows a strange CSS page, not really working. I only want to see code instead... how to do?:(

Answer (score 0):

The browser behaviour you're seeing is correct, in that you've linked to a XSL file, and the browser is displaying it in-screen.

If you're trying to show the contents of the file within your HTML document, there are two options:

- Server-side: use an include to push the file contents into your view
  and style as you wish.
- Client-side: use AJAX to pull the contents of the file on-click and push into your page as a string.

Perhaps if you can give more details/a live link we can help a little more?

Comment: hm, I just have this link on my website and nothing more. I wanted to test if it works and am interested to find out. sry am new to this:(

Comment: No need to appologise!  Perhaps a link to what you're working with would help?